# Sum on null values

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

- URLInfo(uid, *url*, host_ip)
- Stats(sid, *url*, country, platform, source, count)

An "URLInfo" has many "Stats", and I want to obtain the sum of the count attribute for a given "URLInfo". This is easy, and can be done with a join query.

However, for my particular case, when there's no corresponding entry in the "Stats" table, I want to obtain a value of 0 for the sum. sum being an aggregate function entirely ignores the null value, and I cannot come up with the right query.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Showing your solution attempt would be helpful

Comment: @Aegis is it any better now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT u.uid, SUM(IFNULL(s.sid, 0)) AS stats
FROM urlinfo u LEFT JOIN stats s ON u.url = s.url
GROUP BY u.uid;
```

Comment: I think it should be the sum of `count` column, not the `sid` column

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COALESCE` function. It returns the first non-NULL value from the list.

To find the count for a single url, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(count), 0) as total_count 
FROM urlinfo INNER JOIN stats ON urlinfo.id = stats.url
WHERE urlinfo.id = <your_url_id>;
```

For all the urls, you could write the query as:

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(count), 0) as total_count 
FROM urlinfo LEFT JOIN stats ON urlinfo.id = stats.url
GROOUP BY urlinfo.id;
```